# error C2036: 'Agent *const ' : unknown size in 'vector' class

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error occurring in the `vector` class, as in, the class which you access when you `#include < vector >`

I it get only once, and I don't have a clue why it would be occurring:

> error C2036: `'Agent *const '` : unknown size

This is also occurring in vector, and the code that has the error is here:

```
size_type size() const
{   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mylast - this->_Myfirst); // error on this line
}
```

Comment: What is the declaration of your vector ?

Comment: Ok, how are you using the vector class?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This mean that the type `Agent` is not fully known at this point. You probably just have forward-declared it, but don't have a definition visible at this point.

The following piece of code exhibit this error:

```
#include <vector>
class Agent;
static int getSize(std::vector< Agent > const& v) {
    return v.size();
}
```

What you need is to include the file that define the `Agent` class before you use a `std::vector< Agent >`. The file is probably named `Agent.h`.

The reason for the error is because in the line of code you pointed, the compiler try to compute the difference between two `Agent const*`. This is roughly equal to the difference of the pointer casted to `char const*` divided by `sizeof(Agent)`. However, this size is not know if the type is not fully defined.

Comment: Or, as the standard would have it, "instantiating a template with an incomplete type is undefined behaviour" :-)

Comment: Is the forward declaration sufficient in the header of the file where the function exists? Or does the declaration of the function also have to be able to see Agent.h

Comment: Forward-declaration of the class `Agent` is enough if you are only using `std::vector< Agent >` in location where you can use a forward-declared type. This include function parameter and function return value, provided the function is not defined, just declared.