# C++ vector error C2036: 'int (*)[]' : unknown size

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector

I am getting 5 compile errors

> C2036: 'int (*)[]' : unknown size

all from various places in the vector class.

```
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include "Vector2.h"
#include "Vector3.h"
#include "WFObjModel.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace math;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using io::WFObjModel;
using std::unique_ptr;

class Mesh
{
private:
    GLuint textureID;
    unique_ptr<vector<Vector3<float>>> m_vertices;
    unique_ptr<vector<Vector3<float>>> m_normals;
    unique_ptr<vector<Vector2<float>>> m_textureCoordinates;
    unique_ptr<vector<int[]>> m_indices;
public:
    Mesh(unique_ptr<vector<Vector3<float>>> vertices,
        unique_ptr<vector<Vector3<float>>> normals,
        unique_ptr<vector<Vector2<float>>> textureCoordinates,
        unique_ptr<vector<int[]>> indices);

    Mesh(Mesh&& other){
        m_vertices = std::move(other.m_vertices);
        m_normals = std::move(other.m_normals);
        m_textureCoordinates = std::move(other.m_textureCoordinates);
        m_indices = std::move(other.m_indices);
    }

    Mesh& operator=(Mesh&& other)
    {
        m_vertices = std::move(other.m_vertices);
        m_normals = std::move(other.m_normals);
        m_textureCoordinates = std::move(other.m_textureCoordinates);
        m_indices = std::move(other.m_indices);
        return *this;
    }
```

I have looked at the other answers surrounding this issue but the accepted solutions don't seem to work/be applicable.

[error C2036: 'Agent *const ' : unknown size in 'vector' class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077494/error-c2036-agent-const-unknown-size-in-vector-class)
and 
[Forward declaration error when defining a vector type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306492/forward-declaration-error-when-defining-a-vector-type)

Seem to imply that the error is due to the compiler not having a full definition of the type being stored in the vector. I have an include for the header only template class being stored in the vector but I'm guessing it is something to do with the way that template classes are compiled?

I cannot seem to add a forward declaration for the template `class Vector3<float>` without the compiler thinking I am trying to specialize the template.

Comment: `unique_ptr<vector<int[]>> m_indices;` <- How can that possibly work? How would the vector know, for example, what to do if you call `reserve(1)` on it? You probably want either `unique_ptr<vector<int>>` or `unique_ptr<vector<vector<int>>`. You can only have a `vector` of things that have a size known at compile time.

Comment: Yeah, haven't got used to quite how useless C++ arrays are yet.

Comment: they are useless because you have std::vector, std::array, etc...

Comment: @UmNyobe I'll read up on those, thanks.

Comment: @EdwardJBrown: Actually, the problem is that higher-level languages with terrible type names have mistrained you in understanding what an "array" is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem comes from this line:

```
unique_ptr<vector<int[]>> m_indices;
```

You should use a stl container instead, in this case it could be a vector of vector

Also, why would you need a unique_ptr in this case? vectors support move semantics and you could just have a

```
vector<vector<int>> m_indices;
```

An extra hint on move constructors, it is common practice to implement them like this:

```
Mesh(Mesh&& other)
: m_vertices(std::move(other.m_vertices)
, m_normals(std::move(other.m_normals))
, textureCoordinates(std::move(other.m_textureCoordinates))
, indices(std::move(other.m_indices))
{ }
```

Comment: If I have a utility function which creates the vectors on the heap (unique_ptr) and injects them into an instance of the mesh class via the constructor, the vectors need to stay alive inside the instance of mesh class which gets returned from the function which is used to create the vectors. Would this work without the use of unique_ptrs and the creation of the vectors on the stack?

Comment: yes it would! just use normal vectors and move them around! 
before C++11 we had auto_ptr instead of unique_ptr, and we used to do what you're doing to achieve move semantics. Now, especially with stl containers you can just move things around. I find myself using the paradigm that you're using for objects that have no move assignment operator/constructor (i.e. streams in gcc <5.0), or custom objects when I'm lazy to implement move constructor/assignment operators.

Comment: Woah dynamically allocating containers what

Comment: Ok Thanks, that makes sense now, just refactoring several push_back method calls to use a . instead of an -> and to create an std::array instead of the int[].

Comment: heck out also emplace_back, it is useful for more complex types, as it can perform in place construction of objects. push_back in the end is often optimized to basically do the same, but nowadays we tend to emplace things :-)